# Excel: Reformat all date values in a string

Tags: string, excel, date

The text below is my example dataset.  I have notes with dates in a string.  I need to convert all the dates in the string below from the mm/dd/yyyy format to a yyyy-mm-dd.  All of the data is a string in a single cell

Cell Contents:

> '=== NOTE ===
>
> 02/07/2013
>
> Enter Notes Here
>
> '=== NOTE ===
>
> 02/12/2013
>
> Enter Notes Here
>
> '=== NOTE ===
>
> 02/14/2013
>
> Enter Notes Here

Desired Cell Contents:

> '=== NOTE ===
>
> 2013-02-07
>
> Enter Notes Here
>
> '=== NOTE ===
>
> 2013-02-12
>
> Enter Notes Here
>
> '=== NOTE ===
>
> 2013-02-14
>
> Enter Notes Here

I have tried formulas to pick out the date strings and even reformat them, but it will only pick out the first date in the string.  I need something that searches and reformats all the dates in the string.

I can use the following to pick out the first date

> =IFERROR(0+MID(AB2,SEARCH("??/??/????",AB2),10),"")

Then I can use the following to change the format

> =TEXT(AC1,"yyyy-mm-dd")

However, that only picks out the first date and it does not even replace it.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: First select the whole column and right click select `format cells` and select TEXT from categories listed.

Comment: By the way which version of Excel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't going to be possible with a standard Excel function. However, you can use VBA and regular expressions to accomplish this. Create a new Module and add the following code:

```
Function ConvertDates(rng As Range)
    If (rng.Rows.Count > 1 Or rng.Columns.Count > 1) Then
        ConvertDates = CVErr(xlErrRef)
    End If

    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    regex.Global = True
    regex.Pattern = "([\d]{2})/([\d]{2})/([\d]{4})"
    ConvertDates = regex.Replace(rng.Value, "$3-$1-$2")
End Function
```

Then, from a different cell in the worksheet, use the following function:

```
=ConvertDates(A1)
```